# How Get Name Class With Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone i need get name class menu li for load this page

html

```
<body>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="page2" id="page2">PAGE TOW</li>
    <li class="page3" id="page3">PAGE THREE</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="load"></div>
</body>
```

js

```
$(document).on('click','.menu li',function(){
    var Get_Name_Class = //Get Name Class
    if(/* var Get_Name_Class*/).hasClass("page2")) {
      $(".load").load('page2.php');
    }
    else if(/* var Get_Name_Class*/).hasClass("page3")) {
      $(".load").load('page3.php');
    }
});
```

how can i this ( get id or class not difference )

Comment: $(this).attr('class')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this` to refer the clicked element inside the handler callback.

```
$(document).on('click','.menu li',function(){
    // cache the reference
    var $this = $(this);
    // check using the cached element
    if($this.hasClass("page2")) {
      $(".load").load('page2.php');
    }
    else if($this.hasClass("page3")) {
      $(".load").load('page3.php');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using jQuery. If it is class you can do:

```
$(".className")
```

if it is id you can do:

```
$("#idName")
```

if it is just html element you can do:

```
$("elementName")
```

Comment: How does Answer get `.className` of element?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `this.className` with `".php"` concatenated to `.load()`

```
$(document).on('click','.menu li',function() {
  $(".load").load(this.className + ".php") 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click','.menu li',function(){
    // cache the reference
    var $this = $(this);
    // check using the cached element
    if($this.hasClass("page2")) {
      $(".load").load('page2.php');
    }
    else if($this.hasClass("page3")) {
      $(".load").load('page3.php');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="page2" id="page2">PAGE TOW</li>
    <li class="page3" id="page3">PAGE THREE</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="load"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use "#" symbol for id so your code becomes
("#idname")
or u can use "this" which points to the present class u are working on

Answer (score 0):

Don't use classnames. One day you'll add an extra class to those elements and your site will stop working and you'll be left wondering why - or in the worst case it'll slip unnoticed.

Say you have one **or  even more** buttons for `page2` triggering - than it's the perfect place to use the `data-*` attribute!

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-load]', function() {
  
  var page = $(this).data("load");
  console.log(page); // Just to test
  $(".load").load(page +'.php'); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-load="page2">PAGE TWO :) me too</a>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li data-load="page2">PAGE TOW</li>
    <li data-load="page3">PAGE THREE</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="load"></div>
```